# Viewpager and Softkeyboard's Right/Left arrow in Samsung tablets

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-softkeyboard, viewpagerindicator

I have a problem with Viewpager tabs and softkeyboard's right arrow and left arrow in Samsung tablets.

The below images will describe more the context.

[image]

The right/left arrow key press makes the tabs navigation accordingly. How to avoid the navigation. And I couldn't test with other (brand) tablets.
If need more details regarding this problem , let me know. Here I am ready to provide.

Comment: Do you want to stop the navigation on click of these buttons? Is this your question?

Comment: @PrashantSable Yes.

Comment: Check android:imeotions and implement the listener for those.

Comment: @PrashantSable Can we hide those navigation arrows ? Is it possible?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVe did you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Following is the code for handling the key events. Try with this.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  Log.i("your tag", "Keycode: " + keyCode);
  switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
        leftKeyClick();
        return true;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
        rightKeyClick();
        return true;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:
        upKeyClick();
        return true;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
        downKeyClick();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `arrowScroll` function in your ViewPager

Example (in Kotlin):

```
class YourViewPager(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet?): ViewPager(context, attributeSet) {

override fun arrowScroll(direction: Int): Boolean {
  if (shouldStop()) {
    return false
  }
  return super.arrowScroll(direction)
}
```